# How to force app to switch database (different file)?

Tags: android, sqlite

Database file in system depends on current user (username is a part of database name).
There is a usecase: user in system is changed, how to force application to switch database at runtime (basicly to create new DatabseHelper).

It would be easy - create new instance of helper... but helper is not called anywhere - every call to DB is via Provider...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you happen get a solution to this, I have the same issue?  thanks